# How can i find all the references for a clojure symbol in emacs?

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I'm trying to do the same thing that you can accomplish in java + eclipse, that's "find all references for a function or variable". And you end up with the results of an eclipse search, listing all the matches for this symbol in all workspace or project files.

I found an [old post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/AT2vwRo_BI8) on clojure groups but I don't know if there is already some solution to this  problem.

I'm currently using emacs-live with cider

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `rgrep`, `M-x -> rgrep -> <text to search> -> *.clj* -> <root folder>`
Will search in all clj(script) files recursive.